# Global minor mode that requires another during its lifetime

Tags: minor-mode

Say I'm developing a minor mode `A` that happens to need minor mode `B` enabled during its lifetime.

The most straightforward way is to do something like:

```
(define-minor-mode A-mode
  :global t
  :lighter " A"
  (if A-mode
      (B-mode 1)
    (B-mode 0))) ; hooks here are added/removed...
```

Or alternatively:

```
(add-hook 'A-mode-hook 'B-mode)
```

The problem with these approaches is that the original status is not preserved. I could simply use a **global** variable to keep track of it but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

For example I can solve a similar issue involving variables like this:

```
(progn
  (setq foo 10)
  (print foo)     ; 10
  (let ((foo 42))
    (print foo))  ; 42
  (print foo))    ; 10
```

There is one more problem: the user could manually disable minor mode `B` while minor mode `A` is still on; and this shouldn't happen.

Probably is just bad practice to even require this behavior...

*(FYI in my case minor mode `B` is `temp-buffer-resize-mode`.)*

Comment: What about buffer-local variables?

Comment: I'm unsure about how they can be useful in this case, can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I haven't noticed you were defining a global minor mode. That changes things a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem with these approaches is that the original status is not preserved. I could simply use a global variable to keep track of it but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Well I think you'll *essentially* need to do that, but it needn't actually be a defvar'd variable.

If you're using lexical binding, then you can probably just use that.

Alternatively, as it's a global value with no other use-case, you could store it as a symbol property on `A-mode`.

```
(put 'A-mode 'B-mode-enabled (bound-and-true-p B-mode))
```

and then when disabling `A-mode`:

```
(unless (get 'A-mode 'B-mode-enabled)
  (B-mode 0))
```

> There is one more problem: the user could manually disable minor mode B while minor mode A is still on; and this shouldn't happen.

`A-mode` can always add to `B-mode-hook` to at least identify when that happens, even if it doesn't try to actively counter-act it.

> Probably is just bad practice to even require this behavior...

Perhaps. `temp-buffer-resize-mode` is just acting on `temp-buffer-show-hook` to call `resize-temp-buffer-window`, which is something you could probably adapt for `A-mode`'s specific needs.